# hibernate not eagerly loading @any assosciations

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am not able to eagerly load the polymorphic associated objects in hibernate. I understand the default FetchType is Eager for @Any, but I can't eagerly load the fields. Here's a code snippet:

```
@Entity
public class ActionTemplate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name ="protocol_type"),fetch = 
FetchType.EAGER)
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long",metaType = "string",metaValues = {@MetaValue(targetEntity = Http.class,value = "http")})
@JoinColumn(name = "protocol_id")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private ActionProtocol protocol;
}

public interface ActionProtocol {
ProtocolType getType();
}


@Entity
public class Http implements ActionProtocol{
            //some data fields and methods
}
```

I get lazy initialization exception when I fetch it by id from hibernate. I am not able to understand why is this happening. Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Hibernate which is already 10 years old. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3574